# Prove that the tensor product of two CPTP maps is also CPTP

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, density-function, positive-semidefinite

We can take the depolarization map $\mathcal{E}$ as an example, which is defined as:

$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p Tr(\rho)\frac{\mathbb{I}}{2},
$$
for an arbitrary density operator $\rho$ in two dimensions and probability p. It can be proved that $\mathcal{E}$ is completely positive and trace preserving (CPTP). I want to prove that the map $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}$ is also CPTP. How to proceed? Would Choi-Jamiołkowski representation help? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useful thing in you context is the Kraus Decomposition. If $\mathcal E=\sum_jE_j\cdot E_j^*$, then
$$
(\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E)(\rho\otimes\eta)=\sum_{k,j}E_k\rho E_k^*\otimes E_j\eta E_j^*
=\sum_{k,j}(E_k\otimes E_j)(\rho\otimes\eta)(E_k\otimes E_j)^*. 
$$
By linearity this holds for all elements in $M_n(\mathbb C)\otimes M_n(\mathbb C)$.

The trace property is obvious if you know that the trace on the tesor product is the product of the traces. If you don't, take $\{e_k\}$ an orthonormal basis of $H$. Then $\{e_k\otimes e_j\}_{k,j}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H\otimes H$. So
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}((\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E)(\rho\otimes\eta))
&=\sum_{k,j}\langle (\mathcal E(\rho)\otimes\mathcal E(\eta))(e_k\otimes e_j),e_k\otimes e_j\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{k,j}\langle \mathcal E(\rho)e_k\otimes\mathcal E(\eta)e_j,e_k\otimes e_j\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{k,j}\langle \mathcal E(\rho)e_k,e_k\rangle\,\langle\mathcal E(\eta)e_j,e_j\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big(\sum_k\langle \mathcal E(\rho)e_k,e_k\rangle\Big)\,\Big(\sum_k\langle \mathcal E(\eta)e_j,e_j\rangle\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathcal E(\rho))\operatorname{Tr}(\mathcal E(\eta))\\[0.3cm]
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho)\operatorname{Tr}(\eta)\\[0.3cm]
&=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\otimes\eta),
\end{align}
where the last equality is obtained by undoing the previous steps (without $\mathcal E$).

Comment: awesome! thank you...

Comment: Would it also work when the input state is entangled?

Comment: If you are talking about taking sums, everything is linear here.

Comment: I just meant that when you wrote rho tensor eta as the input in the first equation, what if, if the input there is not separable? i.e. a state like bell state?

Comment: And that's what I answered. If you take sums of elementary tensors nothing changes because everything is linear: the sum just goes out.